# How do I select nth tag in html by Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Please see the image below first. 
[image]

And I'm trying to make change to the third element, which is : 
[image]

I'm trying to make changes to the html text in `<a>` tag. However when I try `$('.d-flex').children($('span'))[2].text('someText');`, I get an error that it is a function that does not exist? How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: As your HTML please. This image does not help anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an array index with a jQuery object it returns the DOM element, not a jQuery object. So you can't use a jQuery method with that. The equivalent jQuery operation is the `.eq()` method.

Also, the argument to `.children()` should be a selector, not a jQuery object. So don't call `$()` there.

```
$('.d-flex').children('span').eq(2).text('someText');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nth-child selector using jquery.
Reference URL: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$( ".d-flex span:nth-child(2)" ).text("Your text");
```

Comment: Yes this. You can use CSS pseudo-classes in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$('.d-flex').children($('span'))[2].children[0].text = 'someText';
```

Comment: DOM elements don't hae a `text` property, it's called `innerText`.

Comment: Yup, but author use jquery, I tried agian and success.

Comment: In `jQuery` it's a function you call, not a property you assign to.

Comment: Your answer demonstrates the same confusion as the author, getting confused between jQuery objects and DOM elements.

Comment: oh, thank you so much ^^.